# $this->input->post stops working on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, post, codeigniter-2

I'm new to CI and PHP. A few days ago I was able to use my registration script just fine, but now my script will not post any data anymore.

My "register.php":

```
class Register extends MY_Controller
{
    private $CI; 

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->CI = & get_instance(); 
        $this->CI->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function index($renderData="")
    {   
        $this->title = "title";
        $this->_render('pages/register',$renderData);
    }

    function verify()
    {   
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|max_length[40]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|max_length[40]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
        }
        else
        {       
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            redirect('home','refresh');
        }   
    }
```

}

My "pages/register.php":

```
<body style="background-color: #F7F7F6">
        <section>
            <div class="container register">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="center span4 well">
                        <legend> Create an account</legend>
                        <form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<?php echo base_url('register/verify');?>">
                            <input type="text"  id="username" class="span4" name="username" placeholder="Your Username"/>
                            <input type="password" id="password" class="span4" name="password"placeholder="Your Password" />
                            <p></p>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>      
        <hr style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; BORDER-TOP: #cccccc 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; HEIGHT: 1px"> 
</body>
```

So does anybody have any clue as to why it is not posting the registration information? I remembered to restart XAMPP, nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What have you attempted in regards to debugging the problem?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. CI just doesn't post the data.

Comment: Was this working before?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why it stopped.

Comment: hey man, set your codeigniter state to **"development"** please and after that past your Error Here to solve it with eachother

Answer (score 0):

There is a .htaccess problem. 
You can try this;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
THIS ONE IS MAKING PROBLEMS -> # RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(ACT=.)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.)$ index.php?%1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|css|style.css|favicon.ico|robots.txt|index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.) /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

You should enable mod_rewrite

Comment: Yanlik I did enable mod_rewrite. Doesn't work :(. If I do select * from ci.users; in MySql Workbench it still comes up as null

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Register extends MY_Controller
{
    private $CI; 

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->CI = & get_instance(); 
        $this->CI->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function index($renderData="")
    {   
        $this->title = "title";
        $this->_render('pages/register',$renderData);
    }

    function verify()
    {   
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|max_length[40]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|max_length[40]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('home','refresh');
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all change below line

```
class Register extends MY_Controller
```

with the below

```
class register extends MY_Controller
```

because CI don't accept capital letter in class name.

**EDIT:-**

According to Your current code example , You change below line

```
<form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<?php echo base_url('register/verify');?>">
```

with the below

```
<form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<?php echo base_url();?>register/verify">
```

but I also want to know the folder structure for **Register** class.

Comment: read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html class name should be first letter uppercase. @jsmosis right.

Comment: @user2936213 yes You are correct. I also used to use this. But forgot this time. Thanks for correcting my concept.

Comment: @ripa I checked your edited code and tried it. Still doesn't work :(.  What do you mean by "folder structure for Register class"? It's just a bunch of PHP controllers in the /application/controllers

Comment: what do You mean by this - My "pages/register.php": ? where is Your pages folder?

Comment: You are again wrong @ripa. see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html `<?php echo base_url('register/verify');?>` this will also work!!!

Comment: @ripa I guess I should have been more clearer, "pages/register.php" is in "application/views/pages/register.php".

Comment: does Your validation working or have You checked whether it's going to "verify" function or not?